# C# MVC3 Joining SDF data tables

Tags: c#, database, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I've created an MVC 3 Razor application that manages Projects, and should manage `Sections` within those `Projects`.

So, I've made a model `Projects.cs`, controller `ProjectsController`, and got myself a `Projects.sdf` data table. Works just fine

Then I've added same for `Sections`, but `Sections` should have a field named `projectID` (made it of course) that is connected (joined) with `ID` in `Projects.sdf`; also, I need it to be able to be sorted by `projectID`, and from a `DropDown`

For example: Using `DropDown` to alter the table data. If lets say I select *project1* from Project list, I want the list to show all `Sections` within that `Project` along with CRUD.

I've tried several things but none worked so far, I know how to do this in regular application but not in MVC so I beg for some assistance. Also tried to add `DropDown` in `Sections` view and getting it to populate from `Project` model data, but no good at all.

So I need help on how to do this :(

Please, and thank you.

**Addition**

Project has many Sections, and yes I'm using EF, but as I said not too experienced with it.

as for data context
this is `Project`

```
namespace MyProject.Models
{
    public class Projects
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string projectName { get; set; }
        public string shortDesc { get; set; }
    }

    public class ProjectsDBContext : DbContext 
    {
        public DbSet<Projects> Projects { get; set; }        
    }
}
```

this is `Section`

```
namespace MyProject.Models
{
    public class Sections
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int projectID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }

    public class SectionsDBContext : DbContext 
    {
        public DbSet<Sections> Sections { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Addition 2**

So I made a model named `MyProjectModels.cs`

```
namespace MyProject.Models 
{
    public class Project
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }

    public class Section
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int projectID { {get; set;}
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set;}
    }
}
```

So basically I'm kinda figuring it out. Please let me know if this is ok for models or do I need to put them in separate files? Also, How should i declare context from this point, a hint would be enough :)

Thank you

---

This is the way I have done it. It displays properly but i have NO idea how to utilize it, for example to show different values in a table...

```
<select id="select1" name="select1">
        @foreach (var item in Model.Enrollments)
        {
        <option value=@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Course.Title)>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Course.Title)</option>
        }
</select>
```

by different values in table i meant, when i select different enrollment in this case. i would like to show different values in table.

Comment: Are you using EF?  If so, what does your data context look like?   If not, do you have a sections object and does it have a property for projects?

Comment: also.  Does project have many sections or section has many projects

Comment: Project has many Sections, and yes I'm using EF, but as I said not too experienced with it.

Comment: The Addition will not show the code properly... Maybe it's just me not knowing how to place it right... but it's all there

Comment: to show the code in blocks, just start each line with 4 or more spaces and leave an empty line between the text and the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you really need to have different dbcontexts?   If it is one sdf file then I'm guessing not and your dbcontext should look like

```
namespace MyProject.Models
{
    public class DatabaseContext: DbContext 
    {
         public DbSet<Projects> Projects { get; set; } 
         public DbSet<Sections> Sections{ get; set; }         
    }
}
```

then in your projects model you would have a property for sections

```
namespace MyProject.Models
{
    public class Projects
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string projectName { get; set; }
        public string shortDesc { get; set; }
        public Sections section { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and your sections would just need an id field

```
namespace MyProject.Models
{
    public class Sections
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int projectID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
}
```

As long as your sections class has a primary key field called ID or the id property flagged as the primary key then EF will make the logical leap that Projects has a foreign key of section in the table structure.  your projects model will then have access to the section object.   Biggest hurdle I had with EF was overthinking the database side of things.

Comment: Ok... I think I understood most of that... So basically I don't need two models for this but one... Now that part I dont get really...
I understand databases in general but this whole EF is quite foreign to me... If you don't mind explaining bit closer about file structure i need to have while making those :(

Comment: ok I edited my answer to try to make it a little clearer.  Basically think of the dbcontext class as your database schema and the dbset items as your tables.   Your models are not related to the database but to define the objects that talk to the database.  So your still need a projects and a sections model.  The dbset will read those model objects to determine how to structure the tables.  By having the projects model contain a property of type Section, now your dbcontext has in effect a foreign key of section id in the project table.

Comment: and your project model has access to all of those section properties by way of dot notation i.e. Project.Section.Name, Project.Section.Description  etc.

Comment: I think i get it now. If i'm stuck I'll probably bother you bit more :) Thank you soo much for this.
Would ask nicely of moderators to leave the subject open for now :)

Comment: no problem.  And the questions don't get closed if they are constructive and show some effort on the part of the op as yours does.

Comment: Ok I've tried something out but I can't seem to figure out one thing for now, in which file should i put `DbContext` class? That's kinda confusing. 
I've placed it in `Projects` model but still can't get it to run as I want it to. So which file? :) and sorry for possibly idiot question...

Comment: whether your models are in separate classes or in one class doesn't matter really.  I put them in seperate classes just for clarity sake.  The dbContext stuff needs to be in one "database" class.   Do you have an initializeddatabase class for testing?

Comment: Yes I've scrabbled something up. Anyhow, I've found this tutorial that explained few things you've mentioned : 
[link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg685467.aspx)
 So it's much clearer to me now(still not completely tho -_- but time will do it's bidding...)
Anyhow, I would like to ask another thing. Couldn't find a proper question for it or tutorial data... 
How to populate dropdown in MVC based on a EF column, lets say ProjectId in my case?

Comment: Ok I've found a perfect place to refer to.
[Entity Framework explained](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application)
Hope that this will prove useful for someone else then me.
Thanks a lot for your help Brian. It really helped that you got me to start thinking, I was starting to freak out. :)

Comment: Drop down lists are a little trickier and still give me headaches but basically in your model or in a separate view model you would need to have a select list property then you need to initialize the model or view model and in  your view you can then reference it with the @html.DropDown helper method.    I'll dig through my code to try to find a sample and post it.

Answer (score 0):

For the dropdown list here is the way I have done it

```
public class ChangeUserNameViewModel
{
    public ChangeUserNameViewModel()
    {
        var user = User.GetAllButBuiltIn();
        Users = new SelectList(user, "UserName", "UserName");
    }

    public User User
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [DisplayName("User Name")]
    public SelectList Users
    {
        get;
        set;
    }


    public string UserName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

then in the view I reference the viewmodel

```
@model ChangeUserNameViewModel
@Html.DropDownList("UserName", Model.Users, "Choose")
```

the first parameter is the name of the drop down in the html.  the second the select list to populate it and the third the selected value.   I'm sure there are better ways to do it.  For example you could have an IList in your model and then do a foreach loop in your view.   It all depends on what works best in your case.